# What is the probability of getting exactly two pairs in a poker hand of $7$ cards?

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

Problem:
What is the probability of getting exactly two pairs in a poker hand of
$7$ cards?

Note: Only $5$ cards count, and the cards that count will be determined by
the player holding the cards.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. We will count it as two pairs if there are
two pairs and it is also a flush. We will not count it as two pairs if we
have two kings and three queens.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } (44)(43)(42) }
 { { 52 \choose 7 } } \\
{13 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 13(12) } { 2 } = 78 \\
{ 4 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{4(3)}{2} = 6 \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 78(6)(6) (44)(43)(42) } { { 52 \choose 7 } } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(49)(48)(47)(46) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 3(5)(4)(3) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(16)(47)(46) } { 4(3) }
 = \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } { 3 } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) \\
p &= \dfrac{ 78(6)(6) (44)(43)(42) } { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
\end{align*}
Now we have to simplify the fraction to find $p$.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{  78(3)(3) (44)(43)(42) } {  13(17)(10)(7)(47)(46) }
 = \dfrac{  78(3)(3) (22)(43)(42) } {  13(17)(5)(7)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  78(3)(3) (11)(43)(42) } {  13(17)(5)(7)(47)(23) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  13945932 } { 8361535 } \\
p &\doteq 1.667867 \\
\end{align*}
Where did I go wrong?

Based upon the comments I have gotten, here is a revised solution:

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. We will count it as two pairs if there are
two pairs and it is also a flush. We will not count it as two pairs if we have two kings and three queens hence we need to subtract it out.

\begin{align*}
p &=\dfrac{
 {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } {44 \choose 3}
 -   {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 3 }{4 \choose 2 } {44 \choose 2} }
 { { 52 \choose 7 } } \\
{13 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 13(12) } { 2 } = 78 \\
{ 4 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{4(3)}{2} = 6 \\
{44 \choose 3} &= \dfrac{ 44(43)(42) } { 3(2) } = 44(43)(7) \\
{44 \choose 3} &= 13244 \\
{ 4 \choose 3 } &= 4 \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(49)(48)(47)(46) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 3(5)(4)(3) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(16)(47)(46) } { 4(3) }
 = \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } { 3 } \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
{44 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 44(43) } { 2 } = 22(43) \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) \\
p &= \dfrac{ 78(6)(6)(13244) - 78(4)(6)(22)(43) } { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 17709120 } { 13(17)(5)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 3541824 } { 13(17)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 885456 } { 13(17)(7)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 885456 } { 3344614 } =  \dfrac{ 68112 } { 257278 } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 34056 } { 128639 } \\
p &\doteq 0.2647409
\end{align*}
Now is it right?

Here is my third attempt to get it right.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. We will count it as two pairs if there are two pairs and it is also a flush. We will not count it as two pairs if we have two kings and three queens.

\begin{align*}
p &=\dfrac{
 {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } \left( \dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3(2)} \right) 
 -   {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 3 }{4 \choose 2 } {44 \choose 2} }
 { { 52 \choose 7 } } \\
{13 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 13(12) } { 2 } = 78 \\
{ 4 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{4(3)}{2} = 6 \\
{ 4 \choose 3 } &= 4 \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(49)(48)(47)(46) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 3(5)(4)(3) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(16)(47)(46) } { 4(3) }
 = \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } { 3 } \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
{44 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 44(43) } { 2 } = 22(43) \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) \\
p &=
 \dfrac{ 78(6)(6) \left( \dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3(2)} \right) - 78(4)(6)(22)(43) }
  { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 78(6)(6) \left( 22(10)(12) \right) - 78(4)(6)(22)(43) }
   { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 39(6)(6) \left( 22(10)(12) \right) - 39(4)(6)(22)(43) }
   { 13(17)(5)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 39(6)(6)( 2640 ) - 39(4)(6)(22)(43) } { 13(17)(5)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 39(6)(6)( 2640 ) - 39(4)(6)(22)(43) } { 13(17)(5)(7)(4)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 39(6)(6)( 660 ) - 39(6)(22)(43) } { 13(17)(5)(7)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  705276 } { 13(17)(5)(7)(47)(46) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  352638 } { 13(17)(5)(7)(47)(23) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  352638 } { 8361535 } \\
p &\doteq 0.0421738
\end{align*}
Now is it right?

Here is my fourth attempt to get it right.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. We will count it as two pairs if there are two pairs and it is also a flush. We will not count it as two pairs if we have two kings and three queens.

\begin{align*}
p &=\dfrac{
 {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } \left( \dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3(2)} \right) }
 { { 52 \choose 7 } } \\
{13 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 13(12) } { 2 } = 78 \\
{ 4 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{4(3)}{2} = 6 \\
{ 4 \choose 3 } &= 4 \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(49)(48)(47)(46) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(50)(7)(48)(47)(46) } { 3(5)(4)(3) } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(16)(47)(46) } { 4(3) }
 = \dfrac{ 13(51)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) } { 3 } \\
{ 52 \choose 7 } &= 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &=\dfrac{ 78 (6) (6) \left( \dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3(2)} \right) }
 { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46)  } \\
%
p &=\dfrac{ 78 (6) (6)(44)(40)(6)} { 13(17)(10)(7)(4)(47)(46)  } \\
p &=\dfrac{ 78 (3) (3)(44)(40)(6)} { 13(17)(10)(7)(47)(46)  } \\
p &=\dfrac{ 78 (3) (3)(44)(4)(6)} { 13(17)(7)(47)(46)  } \\
p &=\dfrac{ 78 (3) (3)(44)(2)(6)} { 13(17)(7)(47)(23)  } \\
p &=\dfrac{ 6 (3) (3)(44)(2)(6)} { 17(7)(47)(23)  } \\
p &=\dfrac{ 28512} { 128639 } \\
p &\doteq 0.2216435
\end{align*}
Now is it right?

Comment: "the cards that count will be determined by the player holding the cards" suggests that if you do have two kings and three queens, you may choose the kings, two of the queens, and one of the other three cards.

Comment: @DanielMathias Two kings and three queens does not count as two pair in my book. However, do you have a valid point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \begin{align*}
> p &= \dfrac{ {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } (44)(43)(42) }
>  { { 52 \choose 7 } } 
> \end{align*}

I didn't check the rest of your work that closely.  The above numerator is wrong, because the denominator of $\displaystyle \binom{52}{7}$ presumes that the order that the cards are dealt is unimportant.

Therefore, the numerator must be computed in a consistent manner.  The LHS of the numerator is okay, but the trailing $3$ factors in the numerator should be replaced by $\displaystyle \binom{44}{3}.$

**Edit**
Besides the above major mistake there is an additional subtle flaw.  What happens if you have $3$ pair?  Presumably, that is okay.  However, since a full house has been ruled out, you also have to consider that you could have $2$ pair + trips of a $3$rd rank.  So, even with the $\displaystyle \binom{44}{3}$ correction, you still have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for finding my error. Only $5$ cards count so I think I am okay with the 3 pair case. You are right, I have a problem with 2 pairs and a triple of some other rank.

Comment: @Bob Easy fix is to enumerate and deduct the number of ways of getting $2$ pair + triplet.

Comment: Are you or aren't you allowing for the $3$ pair case? The OP made it explicit that we're only interested in the number of ways to obtain exactly two pairs. I'm getting $$\frac{{13 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}^2\cdot  {11 \choose 3}4^3}{{52 \choose 7}}$$

Comment: @MatthewH. I think you are right. I need to replace ${ 44 \choose 3}$ with $\dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3!}$

Comment: @MatthewH. I have updated my solution based upon your comment. Is my solution right now?

Comment: @MatthewH. Unclear.  The OP (also) specifically said "Only 5 cards count" so I regarded the situation as ambiguous.  That is why, in the trailing part of my answer, I indicated the issue without taking a stand.  At the time of my answer, I suspect that the OP had not even considered the issue.  In general, for someone giving an answer, it is not a good idea to try to hit a moving target (AKA the shooting gallery blues).

Comment: @Bob No, your answer is still wrong.  The factor of $$\frac{44 \times 40 \times 36}{3 \times 2}$$ is clever and effective.  However, you followed that with a term in the numerator that represents a deduction.  That deduction should be removed as obselete.  I am assuming here, that $3$ pair is to be avoided, as is a full house.

Comment: @user2661923 Are you saying that it should be: $p =\dfrac{
 {13 \choose 2} { 4 \choose 2 }{4 \choose 2 } \left( \dfrac{44(40)(36)}{3(2)} \right)  }
 { { 52 \choose 7 } } $ ?

Comment: @Bob, yes, assuming that 3 pair is outlawed as well as 2 pair + trips.  In the numerator, the RHS refers to selecting one of 1 rank, one of a different rank, and then one of a 3rd rank.

Comment: @user2661923 I have updated my post. I am hoping you can now tell me that my solution is right.

Comment: @Bob Yes, your solution looks good, under the assumption that both 3 pair is outlawed, and 2 pair + trips is outlawed.  I verified the computation with my calculator.